IMAP Shared mailbox in MS Outlook mailboxes: Share sent messages / responses
There is a Dovecot IMAP based mail server. The client software is the current MS Outlook desktop app. (Exchange, MAPI or M365 cloud are not used as a backend!)
There is a central email address like info@example.org. Each user has a personal mailbox as well, e.g. john.doe@....
In IMAP, info@... is included as a "shared" inbox in the mailbox of john.doe@... and others.
This works. Every user can access the shared inbox.
But: Whenever john.doe@... responds to a message in the "shared" inbox info@..., the sent message is put into the 'Sent Items' folder of his personal IMAP mailbox. So all other users, who share the info@... mailbox, cannot see john.doe@... already has answered this issue.
I thought about an Outlook client-side rule: When an email is sent from / in the name of info@..., copy it to a subfolder of the shared mailbox inbox (e.g. "Shared Sent Items").
Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Outlook shows synchronization problems although the client/user can read/write access the "Shared Sent Items" folder.
Have you already solved a similar task or did you manage to solve this specific issue?

By default, messages sent from the shared mailbox aren't saved to the Sent Items folder of the shared mailbox. Instead, they are saved to the Sent Items folder of the person who sent the message.
As a workaround, you can enable the Outlook registry option called DelegateSentItemsStyle (set its value to 1) to save messages sent on behalf of a common user mailbox.

Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
Locate and then click the following registry subkey:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Outlook\Preferences
On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
Type DelegateSentItemsStyle, and then press Enter.
Right-click DelegateSentItemsStyle, and then click Modify.
In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.
Exit Registry Editor.

